# Folder action with Automator file search

Tags: automator, folder-action

Since a couple of years, I used the folder action successfully which is shown in the screenshot:

1. A file is added to "Downloads"
2. "Find Finder Items" with the shown criteria is executed
3. If the filename fulfils the criteria, the file is moved to another folder. If not, the file remains in folder "Downloads"

Since I bought a new iMac, this action moves **every** downloaded file to the specified folder (see picture). What is wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to replace `Find Filter Items` with `Filter Finder Items`